# Pandas - Apply groupby transform to a datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following df:

```
df

   Day   Name       Hour
1   M    John     10:00:00
2   M    John     11:00:00
3   M    John     14:00:00
4   T    Maria    20:00:00
5   T    Maria    22:30:00
```

Hour is a datetime column. My goal is to get a new column with the difference between earliest and latest hour of a group (John it's 4 hours, Maria only has 2, so 2h30). Here is the desired output:

```
df

   Day   Name       Hour      Delay
1   M    John     10:00:00      4
2   M    John     11:00:00      4
3   M    John     14:00:00      4
4   T    Maria    20:00:00      2.5
5   T    Maria    22:30:00      2.5
```

And here is what I tried but i'm stuck:

`df['Delay']=df.groupby(['Day','Name']).transform((max(df['Hour'])-min(df['Hour']))`

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```py
df['Delay'] = (df.groupby(['Day','Name'])['Hour']
               .transform(lambda col: (pd.to_datetime(str(col.max())) - pd.to_datetime(str(col.min()))).seconds/3600))
```

```
print(df)

  Day   Name      Hour  Delay
1   M   John  10:00:00    4.0
2   M   John  11:00:00    4.0
3   M   John  14:00:00    4.0
4   T  Maria  20:00:00    2.5
5   T  Maria  22:30:00    2.5
```

Comment: could you please let me know why you used `str(col.max())` instead of just `col.max()`

Comment: @KarthikS OP's `Hour` column is datetime type which couldn't be accepted by `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: completely forgot to use lambda, thanks!

Comment: Actually, it's working even without `str` as the `Hour` column is already an `object` datatype

Comment: @KarthikS OP says it's a datetime column

Comment: ah, ok thanks, sorry was confused